# Removing all rows that do not meet criteria in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I can't seem to find such a solution on here similar to my scenario. Here is a column in my example dataset:

```
How_do_you_feel

Excited, Hopeful, Prepared, good    
Unsure, confused, anxious, curious  
Co operations, Teamwork, communication, critical thinking   
a   
First, team work, nervous, curious  
Interesting. New. Exciting. Develop 
perplexedï¼Œanxiousï¼Œembarrassedï¼Œbit excited 
Novel, Unknown, Challenging, Useful 
Worried, excited, self-doubt, motivated 
Excited,curious,nervous,worried
```

The correct format should be 4 words, separated by a comma in between like this '**Excited, Hopeful, Prepared, good**'.

How do I clean my data in a way that it removes all the rows that have the wrong format, such as
'Interesting. New. Exciting. Develop' or 'perplexedï¼Œanxiousï¼Œembarrassedï¼Œbit excited'?

So the result would look something like this:

```
How_do_you_feel

Excited, Hopeful, Prepared, good    
Unsure, confused, anxious, curious  
Co operations, Teamwork, communication, critical thinking 
First, team work, nervous, curious
Novel, Unknown, Challenging, Useful 
Worried, excited, self-doubt, motivated
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One generalized rule which appears to apply to your situation is that having three commas followed by a space (not just a comma as in previous answers) means a good match. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

read_delim("How_do_you_feel

Excited, Hopeful, Prepared, good    
Unsure, confused, anxious, curious  
Co operations, Teamwork, communication, critical thinking   
a   
First, team work, nervous, curious
Interesting. New. Exciting. Develop 
perplexedï¼Œanxiousï¼Œembarrassedï¼Œbit excited 
Novel, Unknown, Challenging, Useful 
Worried, excited, self-doubt, motivated 
Excited,curious,nervous,worried", delim = "\\n") %>%
  mutate(How_do_you_feel = str_trim(How_do_you_feel)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(How_do_you_feel, paste("^", paste(rep("[[:alpha:]- ]+", times = 4), collapse = ", "), "$", sep = "")))

#   How_do_you_feel                                               
#   <chr>                                                         
# 1 "Excited, Hopeful, Prepared, good    "                        
# 2 "Unsure, confused, anxious, curious  "                        
# 3 "Co operations, Teamwork, communication, critical thinking   "
# 4 "First, team work, nervous, curious  "                        
# 5 "Novel, Unknown, Challenging, Useful "                        
# 6 "Worried, excited, self-doubt, motivated "
```

Comment: I doubt this will work since it is hard coding the part comma is 3. But in my dataset there might be cases where there 3 commas but not in the correct format

Comment: What are some examples of that?

Comment: Such as: nervousï¼Œperplexedï¼Œdifficultï¼Œscarednervousï¼,,,Œperplexedï¼Œdifficultï¼Œscarednervousï¼Œperplexedï¼Œdifficultï¼Œscared

Comment: How about these edits?